# WP7 Mango causes MissingMethodException in constructor

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my constructor of a class, I call a virtual member. Whether this should or should not be done is out of scope for my question.

WORKS (can call in my constructor):

```
 protected void DoSomething();
 protected virtual void DoSomething();
```

DOES NOT WORK

```
 protected override void DoSomething();
```

The DOES NOT WORK part is located in the same library, the derived class has the same visibility, etc. As soon as I override the (virtual or abstract) DoSomething defined in class A in my Class B, I get a MissingMethodException as soon as the method is executed.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Are you using any third party DLLs or is this a basic set up with just the WP7 SDK stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of debugging, trying, etc, it seems that a class I used inside the method derived from an interface with this definition:

```
public interface IMyInterface<out TValueInterface>
```

It seems you cannot use covariant type parameters, otherwise you will get this exception.

For more information, see [this blog post](http://blog.catenalogic.com/post/2011/08/27/Windows-Phone-7-and-MissingMethodException.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you created the project with the beta 1 of the SDK.

Try again in a new project and you won't encounter the problem :-p !